# message box in Oracle BI Publisher 10g

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

In Oracle BI Publisher 10g, I have two parameters for from date and to date and the date entered in to date should be greater than from date. How can I display a message so that the user is prompted to re-enter the to date.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can show a message box in BI Publisher. The best way to do is to show the alert text in the blank report (since the query won't return any data) when the user enters such dates.

Other option would be to default the `from_date` with `{$SYSDATE()$}` and `to_date` with `{$SYSDATE()+7$}` i.e. one week range from today's date.